# $\|\phi_{\lambda}- \phi_{\lambda} \ast f \|_{L^{2}(\mathbb R)}\to 0$ as $\lambda \to \infty$? ($\phi_{\lambda}(x)=\lambda^{-1} \phi(x/\lambda).$)

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, fourier-analysis, lp-spaces

For $f\in L^{1}(\mathbb R),$ we define its Fourier transform as follows: $\hat{f}(t)=\int_{\mathbb R} f(x) e^{-ix\cdot t} dx ,(t\in \mathbb R).$

Suppose that $f\in L^{1}(\mathbb R)$ with $\hat{f}(0)=1.$

Let $\phi\in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb R),$ (Schwartz space).
For $\lambda >0,$ we define, $\phi_{\lambda}(x)=\lambda^{-1} \phi(x/\lambda).$
Then $\|\phi_{\lambda}- \phi_{\lambda} \ast f \|_{L^{1}(\mathbb R)}\to 0$ as $\lambda \to \infty.$

[Since $\hat{f}(0)=1,$ for $x\in \mathbb R,$ we have, $\phi_{\lambda}(x)-\phi_{\lambda}\ast f(x) = \int_{\mathbb R} f(y) (\phi_{\lambda}(x)-\phi_{\lambda}(x-y)) dy;$ so $\|\phi_{\lambda}-\phi_{\lambda}\ast f\|_{L^{1}(\mathbb R)} \leq \int_{\mathbb R} |f(y)|(\int_{\mathbb R}\lambda^{-1}|(\phi(x/\lambda)- \phi ((x-y)/\lambda)| dx) dy= \int_{\mathbb R}|f(y)|( \int_{\mathbb R} (\phi(z)-\phi(z-\lambda^{-1}z)| dz)dy$

;and the inner integral is at most $2\|\phi\|_{L^{1}},$ and it tends to zero for every $y\in \mathbb R,$ as $\lambda \to \infty.$ Hence by dominated convergence theorem, we get, $\|\phi_{\lambda}- \phi_{\lambda} \ast f \|_{L^{1}(\mathbb R)}\to 0$ as $\lambda \to \infty.$]

> **My Question is**: (1) Suppose $f\in L^{2}(\mathbb R)$ with $\hat{f}(0)=1.$ Then can we expect, 
>   $\|\phi_{\lambda}- \phi_{\lambda} \ast f \|_{L^{2}(\mathbb R)}\to 0$ as $\lambda \to \infty  ?$
>   (2) If answer is yes, can we expect similar result for other $L^{p}$ ?

**Edit**: It is well-known that, for $f\in L^{p}, (1\leq p <\infty),$ we have $\|f-\phi_{\lambda}\ast f\|_{L^{p}} \to 0$ as $\lambda \to 0.$ (Bit roughly speaking, approximate identity )

Comment: Did you try to prove the approximation result without using any Fourier transform? Because everything here looks really similar to the usual approximation via mollifiers.

Comment: @Siminore; thanks for the attention;[Bit roughly speaking, this fact tells us that $f$ is approximated, in the $L^{1}-$ norm, by a function $f+h$ whose Fourier transform is constant in some neighbourhood of the point $x_{0}; for detail, please see, this question:(http://mathoverflow.net/questions/176541/how-f-is-approximated-in-the-lp-norm-by-a-function-fh-whose-fourier)]; but I could not follow what you trying to say; would you please tell me bit more; thanks;

Comment: @Siminore; what are approximation results via mollifiers ?; thanks;

Comment: I'm sorry, I realize now that my eyes read something and my brain swapped two symbols... My comment is totally useless, I guess.